# While saving parent and child objects in Mongoose, it stores reference of parent, but the parent doesnt store reference to child

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

The problem in nutshell is that I am using Mongoose with below code to create and save db entries in parent schema `Blogpost` and in child schema `Relatedcomment` but when I query it the _id of parent object does show in child object, but `in the parent object no child shows up at all`. In other words `the child knows who the parent is, but the parent doesnt know who is its child`. Please help me out how to reach the child object `while querying parent object`. The code is below

Below are the schema of parent object ie Blogpost
`blogpost.js`

```css
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogpostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 
  image:String,
  title:String,
  related_comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Relatedcomment' }],
});

mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogpostSchema);
```

Below is the schema of child object ie Relatedcomment
`relatedcomment.js`

```css
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const RelatedcommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  blogpost: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blogpost' }, 

  user_name: String,
  comment: String,
});

mongoose.model('Relatedcomment', RelatedcommentSchema);
```

Below is how I am saving parent object, with child object. Observe I am passing _id to blogpost, and its child too as blogpost._id

```css
require('../models/blogpost');
require('../models/relatedcomment');
const Blogpost = mongoose.model('Blogpost');
const Relatedcomment = mongoose.model('Relatedcomment');

// db_object_dict and child_db_object_dict are objects containing key value pairs according to their schemas

const blogpost = new Blogpost( {...db_object_dict, _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()} )
blogpost.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
            const related_child = new Relatedcomment( {...child_db_object_dict, blogpost: blogpost._id} )
            related_child.save(function (err) {
              if (err) return handleError(err);
            });
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it and the way I solved it is using below code

```
const blogpost = new Blogpost( {...db_object_dict, _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()} )
blogpost.save(function (err, blogpost) { // passed blogpost as well in arguments
    if (err) return handleError(err);
            const related_child = new Relatedcomment( {...child_db_object_dict, blogpost: blogpost._id} )

            related_child.save(function (err) {
              if (err) return handleError(err);
            });
            // new added line
            blogpost.relatedcomments.push(relatedcomment._id)
        }
        // new added line
        blogpost.save() 
    }
```

Actually my mistake was that I was not pushing relatedcomment._id (child id) in the blogpost.relatedcomments array, and then saving it. Done both and my problem solved.